# Do JavaScript events last forever?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

So let's say I use `var evt = new CustomEvent("example");` to create a new event.

I am unable to reuse the newly created event object later on in the program because it's `.detail` property is read-only. If I could modify this value, I could dispatch this custom event multiple times with different data associated with it.

I want to dispatch this custom event during a built-in "click" event-handler function. Because I can't reuse the custom event, I'm creating a new one every time someone clicks on the target element.

Of course, this isn't much of a problem if the events get deleted at some point. Maybe there's some sort of garbage collection for when a variable that stores an event goes out of scope?

Or do they just linger around in the freestore until the current browser context is closed?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is garbage collected (of course it is, any language that does not impose manual memory management onto the developer is). So yes, variables that are not longer used are garbage collected eventually.  Your question has a "premature optimization" smell to it. Don't optimize for memory usage at this level. Just create new event objects as and when you need them, end of story.

Comment: I think the garbage collection would have to be after the event-handler function has completed, surely? Even with garbage collection, it still seems inefficient to be unable to reuse events. Especially since creating an event would probably take a fair bit of time, and custom events are often fired in tandem with built-in events to maintain modularity between files.

Comment: When you move the mouse a few centimeters over your screen, hundreds or thousands of mousemove, mouseenter, mouseleave events are created and thrown away immediately. You think about "inefficient" on the completely wrong level. Stop worrying and build something. Make it more efficient when it works and you notice that it is slow.

Comment: Good point. At least now I understand.

Comment: It's not wrong to think about these things. But it's wrong to optimize for something of which you don't even know if it's going to be a problem or not, just because of a gut feeling. Make it work first, make it faster after that. Classical read: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization, also related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil (especially the statement *"optimization without first measuring is almost always premature."*)